# com.qualcomm.embms keeps popping up every few minutes

Tags: 5.1-lollipop, bugs, lenovo

In Lenovo Phab, a message : "Unfortunately, com.qualcomm.embms has stopped." keeps popping up exactly twice every few minutes, to which I've to click 'OK' every time. 
I've tried force stopping it from the settings manually but it's still going on. I've scanned the device with McAfee but there are no threats. But a Quadrooter scan tells me I've the following vulnerability : (CVE-2016-2504). 
Is it possibly popping up because of that? Or is it just a bug? What should I do to make it stop popping up? Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score -2):

A new widespread vulnerability that affects millions of Android devices around the world could allow hackers to read your SMS text messages, phone records, and perform any capabilities the radio allows.

This hack involves the netd daemon, which is the network interface in Android. The problem arose when Qualcomm released new Application Program Interfaces (APIs) as part of the network_manager system service, which also involved the netd daemon. These APIs allowed additional tethering capabilities.This vulnerability is labeled as [CVE-2016-2060](https://www.fireeye.com/blog/threat-research/2016/05/exploiting_cve-2016-.html) with a medium risk.

Devices ranging from Gingerbread to Lollipop are likely affected. So, **if you can upgrade your android that would be the best option**.

Also, The [FireEye](https://www.fireeye.com/) Mobile Security app will detect the Qualcomm vulnerability, but it’s only for enterprise customers. If you have a corporate phone, check with your administrator to find out if your company subscribes to the service.

The good news is that FireEye has been monitoring the use of the API, and hasn’t found any occurrences of it being exploited. However, that could change as hackers learn of the flaw.

Looking at the big picture, it’s still more unlikely than likely that you will fall victim to an attack.

You can read more about this issue in this [blog](https://www.digitaltrends.com/mobile/qualcomm-security-threat-news/).